# Converting a string of numbers to a byte array, keeping their display value.

Tags: c#, arrays

My application gets data from a hardware device which is represented as a string, EG XYZ*012. I split the string up so I get “012” which I need to convert to an array of bytes.

The problem I have is that I want each digit to keep its value so the character “0” will be stored in a byte as 0 and character “1” will be stored in the byte as 1 etc. 
This is required because I need to work on the bits of the bytes. I’ve tried using the “GetBytes” command but it converts “0” into 48 which is not what I want.

Is there a command to do what I want or do I need to manually handle each character in the string separately in a loop?

Comment: Try just subtract 48 from each byte value...

Comment: @Rubens: Pheew. Always use/say: subtract '0' from each (char) value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will normalize text character numbers, to their byte number equivalents:

```
byte[] bytes = data.Select(c => (byte)(c - '0')).ToArray();
```

Comment: char is a type, you need @char. Better use another name. And who wants to know/remember that 48 == '0' ? Think of the poor reader.

Comment: @Henk Interesting point re. 48. It looks more obvious to me that normalization is going on.

Comment: `ch - '0'` tells a logical story, it is self-documenting.  `ch - 48` requires knowledge of ASCII codes. .

Comment: @Henk We are converting from ASCII, therefore, a knowledge of ASCII or a hint that is what's going on is useful. Replacing it with a meaningful constant would be helpful (e.g. AsciiAdjust), but we're allowed brevity fro code samples.

Comment: No, we are converting from some (preferably unknown) char encoding.

Comment: We are actually converting from Ascii.

Comment: Wow, loads of answers in a short space of time. I’ve gone for this answer as it does exactly what I need in a neat single line way. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
string numString = "012";
var numChars = numString.ToCharArray();
var result = new byte[numChars.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < numChars.Length; i++)
{
   result[i] = System.Convert.ToByte(numChars[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a loop. You want a particualr conversion which is not standard:

```
string numString = "012";

var byteDigits = new byte[numString.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < byteDigits.Length; i++)
    byteDigits[i] = (byte)(numString[i] - '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "012";
byte[] bytes = s.Select(c => byte.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't get the -1, it's a working solution. Just needed a ')'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand as what you want to achieve, Is this

```
List<byte> lstint = byval.Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c.ToString())).ToList();
```

For a Byte array

```
byte[] bytarr = byval.Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: Strings already present a char enumerator, no need for ToCharArray. OP was also after a byte[].

Comment: A `List<byte>` is not a `byte[]`

Comment: @Henk Ok .. changed for the byte[] version, thank chibacity .. i missed that part

Answer (score 0):

using System.Linq you can do this.  This will also skip over non digits.

```
var sourceString="012";
var result = sourceString.Where(c=>c>='0' && c<='9').Select(c=>(byte)(c-'0')).ToArray();
```

or if you want invalid characters to just be 255 you could do

```
var result = sourceString.Select(c=> (c>='0' && c<='9') ? (byte)(c-'0') : 255).ToArray();
```